# Async actually not async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

The following code:

```js
function log() {
    console.log('ok');
}
function log2() {
    console.log('ok2');
}

async function run() {
    await log();
    await log2();
}

run();

console.log(1);
```

Returns:

```
ok
1
ok2
```

The question is: being "run" an async function shouldn't it execute after all synchronous calls? (Such as `console.log(1)`). Actually the one that executes after the sync call is the second `await`.

The return value should be:

```
1
ok
ok2
```

Why does the first await executes synchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my understanding of it.  `async`/`await` is just syntactical sugar for `Promises`.  Your logs aren't actually async and they return `undefined`.

However, since you say `await log()` that turns into `Promise.resolve(log())` and the code after is put into a `.then()`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

> If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a
> Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.

Whenever you return the `Promise` you "defer" until other synchronous stuff is done, much like a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` would do.  Because of that, you don't see "ok2" until after the synchronous portion is complete.

That's the other important bit.  It won't run the rest of the asynchronous stuff because it has been put into a callback queue and that isn't processed until the synchronous stuff is done.  See [Concurrency model and the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) for a deeper explanation of how things are handled "later".

```js
function log() {
    console.log('ok');
}
function log2() {
    console.log('ok2');
}

async function run() {

  //await log();
  /*
   * log is called immediately and the await wraps the
   * return value in a resolved Promise, the next await
   * statement will wait for the resolved Promise which
   * pushes the callback execution to the internal runtime queue
   */
  Promise.resolve(log())
  // await log2()
  /*
   * This won't get executed until the synchronous runtime
   * runs out of stuff to do.  Once it does, this will get
   * executed
   */
    .then(() => Promise.resolve(log2()));
}

run(); // Synchronous

console.log(1); // The other synchronous stuff to do
```

Comment: Clear as water, Is there any documentation explaining this phenomena?

Answer (score 4):

> being "run" an async function shouldn't it execute after all synchronous calls?

No.

Marking a function with the `async` keyword:

- Makes it return a promise
- Allows the use of the `await` keyword inside it

It does not make synchronous code asynchronous. It does not move code to another thread. It does not immediately pause the execution of the `async` function.

---

So when you call `run`, it calls `log`, which calls `console.log` (**ok**), then returns `undefined`. The `await` keyword causes `run` to go to sleep until the returned promise settles.

The main part of the program continues running and it **logs 1**.

The promise settles immediately (because it is `undefined` and not a promise), so `run` wakes up and calls `log2`.

Comment: Your answer actually made me go back and read the spec.  I wasn't clear on the fact that `await` is what actually does the promisifying.  The difference is subtle, but important as it means the difference between a normal function returning `Promise.resolve(undefined)` vs just `undefined`.  Could you check my answer and tell me if I am clear now?

Comment: @zero298 — No. The `async` keyword makes the function return a promise. It is `await` that makes the function go to sleep so other code can run.

Answer (score -2):

Async is something happening behind the scenes. That means if a code finishes executing, it outputs or returns. On the other hand, the synchronous code will run as usual. In the above code, you are console logging a text. That doesnt require much time to execute. So its outputted just as it finishes. Try using setTimeout in async code and you can see the synchronous code execute first